# using char * in C (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, void-pointers

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  char *A, B, C, D;
  printf("Enter name A:");
  scanf("%s", &A);


  printf("Enter name B:");
  scanf("%s", &B);

  printf("Enter name C:");
  scanf("%s", &C);

  printf("Enter name D:");
  scanf("%s", &D);

  printf("%s, %s, %s, %s \n", A, B, C, D);    

  return 1;
}
```

it accepts four strings but crashes before printing them out?

the second thing I would like to do, is pass those strings(A,B,C,D) to a function that accepts void pointers, would I have to cast them to a void pointer first??

Comment: Your problem is that B,C,D are not `char*`! You need to attach a `*` before each of them when you declare them (not the only problem - also need to allocate memory)

Comment: Change the declaration line to: `char *A, *B, *C, *D;` and of course you need to use `malloc()` to allocate dynamic-memory, or to use local char-arrays instead

Comment: Note that `char *A, *B, *C, *D;` isn't the same as `char *A, B, C, D;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allocate space for `A`, you are using `scanf()` the wrong way, the `"%s"` specifier does not allocate space for the destination variable.

You can just allocate space in the stack by declaring `A` as an array of fixed size, like this

```
char A[100];
```

then

```
if (scanf("%99s", A) != 1)
 {
    printf("unexpected problem, probably `EOF'\n");
    return -1;
 }
```

also, this

```
char *A, B, C, D;
```

is not what you apparently think, the `*` only applies to `A` there, so maybe you meant

```
char *A, *B, *C, *D;
```

One last thing, `"%s"` specifier expects a `char *` i.e. a `char` pointer, by using the `&` address of operator you are passing `char **` which is wrong, so you don't need it in this case.

Comment: would it be better to use dynamic memory allocation since I don't know what the size if the incoming string is?? is there a draw back to this method??

Comment: keep in mind, that I want to pass these strings to a function that accepts a void pointer

Comment: It would be too hard, and you can pass them to a function taking `void *` or `char *` because `void *` is converted to any kind of pointer and viceversa, so that's why you for example don't need to cast `malloc()`, what you can't do is return them from a function.